# Change string to byte but the format is string

Tags: python-3.x, encode

I want to encode string to unicode like

```
   >>> s = 'Hello, 안녕'
   >>> u = s.encode('raw_unicode_escape')
   b'Hello, \\uc548\\ub155'
   >>> doing something
   >>> print(u)
   Hello, \uc548\ub155
```

I would like to show Unicode itself as string so if I write a file
`Hello, \uc548\ub155` is showing the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you need, so here are some examples:

### Unicode Direct

```
>>> s = 'Hello, 안녕'
>>> print(s)
Hello, 안녕
```

### Unicode \u Codes

```
>>> s = u'Hello, \uc548\ub155'
>>> print(s)
Hello, 안녕
```

### Unicode → ByteString

```
>>> u = s.encode('raw_unicode_escape')
>>> print(u)
b'Hello, \\uc548\\ub155'
```

### ByteString → Unicode

```
>>> u = u.decode('unicode_escape')
>>> print(u)
Hello, 안녕
```

### Translator function

```
>>> def _(unicode_text):
    return unicode_text.encode('unicode_escape')

. . .

>>> s = f'Hello, {_("안녕")}'
>>> print(s)
Hello, b'\\uc548\\ub155'
```

Comment: No I mean I want to write file exactly "Hello, \uc548\ub155" this form, from "Hello, 안녕" which is opposite of your answer.

Comment: If you write your strings in the file like u'Hello, \uc548\ub155' then they will work... is that the solution?

Comment: But I want to do it as automatically, like from s = 'Hello, 안녕' to "Hello, \uc548\ub155"  in file. not manually type u'Hello, \uc548\ub155' is there is way?

Comment: Take a look at my most recent edit, perhaps this is what you need. 
I also suggest you look through this article, there may be some information that helps you out https://realpython.com/python-encodings-guide/#enter-unicode